# Jackson: deserialize JSON to Scala ADT

Tags: scala, jackson

Suppose you have a JSON which looks like this:

```
[{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}, {"foo": 3, "bar": {"baz": 4}}]
```

It seems natural to try to represent this using a Scala sum type:

```
sealed trait Item
case class IntItem(foo: Int, bar: Int) extends Item
case class Baz(baz: Int)
case class BazItem(foo: Int, bar: Baz) extends Item
```

My question is: is it possible to use Jackson's Scala module to serialize the JSON above into a `List[Item]`?

My attempt:

```
val string = "[{\"foo\": 1, \"bar\": 2}, {\"foo\": 3, \"bar\": {\"baz\": 4}}]"
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
mapper.readValue[List[Item]](string)
```

The exception:

> Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of ...Item, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
>    at [Source: [{"foo": 1, "bar": {"baz": 2}}, {"foo": 3, "bar": {"baz": 4}}]; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.BuilderWrapper[0])

That makes it fairly clear what the problem is, but I'm not sure how best to fix it.

Comment: I'll just add that if you replace `"bar": 2` with `"bar": {"baz": 2}` and `List[Item]` with `List[BazItem]` then everything works fine, so it really is an issue with ADT's.

Comment: I am just wondering ... if, say, you were to implement Jackson, how would you go about guessing into which type each of the list elements should be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

As @Dima pointed out, I don't think there exists a generic solution that covers all the cases. Moreover I'm not sure it can exist at all because the difference might be hidden arbitrary deep and I suspect someone smart enough can create a [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) from that. However many specific cases can be solved.

First of all, if you control both sides (serialization and deserialization), you should consider using [`JsonTypeIdResolver`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonTypeIdResolver.html) annotation with some of [`TypeIdResolver`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/TypeIdResolver.html) subclasses that will put name of the type in the JSON itself.

If you can't use `JsonTypeIdResolver`, probably the only solution is to roll out your custom `JsonDeserializer` as the error suggests. The example you provided in your question can be handled by something like this:

```
sealed trait Item
case class IntItem(foo: Int, bar: Int) extends Item
case class Baz(baz: Int)
case class BazItem(foo: Int, bar: Baz) extends Item



import com.fasterxml.jackson.core._
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind._
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBuffer
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node._
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc._
import java.io.IOException

class ItemDeserializer() extends StdDeserializer[Item](classOf[Item]) {

  @throws[IOException]
  @throws[JsonProcessingException]
  def deserialize(jp: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): Item = {
    // 1) Buffer current state of the JsonParser
    // 2) Use firstParser (from the buffer) to parser whole sub-tree into a generic JsonNode
    // 3) Analyze tree to find out the real type to be parser
    // 3) Using the buffer roll back history and create objectParser to parse the sub-tree as known type
    val tb = new TokenBuffer(jp, ctxt)
    tb.copyCurrentStructure(jp)

    val firstParser = tb.asParser
    firstParser.nextToken
    val curNode = firstParser.getCodec.readTree[JsonNode](firstParser)

    val objectParser = tb.asParser
    objectParser.nextToken()

    val bar = curNode.get("bar")
    if (bar.isInstanceOf[IntNode]) {
      objectParser.readValueAs[IntItem](classOf[IntItem])
    }
    else if (bar.isInstanceOf[ObjectNode]) {
      objectParser.readValueAs[BazItem](classOf[BazItem])
    }
    else {
      throw ctxt.reportBadDefinition[JsonMappingException](classOf[Item], "Unknown subtype of Item") // Jackson 2.9
      //throw InvalidDefinitionException.from(jp, "Unknown subtype of Item", ctxt.constructType(classOf[Item])) // Jackson 2.8
    }
  }
}
```

and then you can use it as following

```
def test() = {
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala._
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental._

  val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

  // add our custom ItemDeserializer
  val module = new SimpleModule
  module.addDeserializer(classOf[Item], new ItemDeserializer)
  mapper.registerModule(module)

  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

  val string = "[{\"foo\": 1, \"bar\": 2}, {\"foo\": 3, \"bar\": {\"baz\": 4}}]"

  val list = mapper.readValue[List[Item]](string)
  println(list.mkString(", "))
}
```

which prints

> IntItem(1,2), BazItem(3,Baz(4))

The main trick in the `ItemDeserializer` is to use `TokenBuffer` to parse JSON twice: first time to analyze the JSON-tree and find out as what type it should be parsed as, second time to actually parse the object of a known type.